# How to load images and text labels for CNN regression from different folders

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have two folders, X_train and Y_train. X_train is images, Y_train is vector and .txt files. I try to train CNN for regression.

I could not figure out how to take data and train the network. When i use "ImageDataGenerator" , it suppose that X_train and Y_train folders are classes.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.chdir(r'C:\\Data')
from glob2 import glob

x_files = glob('X_train\\*.jpg')
y_files = glob('Y_rain\\*.txt')
```

Above, i found destination of them, how can i take them and be ready for model.fit ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes sure `x_files` and `y_files` are sorted together, then you can use something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from glob2 import glob
import os

x_files = glob('X_train\\*.jpg')
y_files = glob('Y_rain\\*.txt')

target_names = ['cat', 'dog']

files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_files, y_files))

imsize = 128

def get_label(file_path):
    label = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    return tf.cast(label == target_names, tf.int32)

def decode_img(img):
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(images=img, size=(imsize, imsize))
    return img

def process_path(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    return img, label

train_ds = files.map(process_path).batch(32)
```

Then, `train_ds` can be passed to `model.fit()` and will return batches of 32 pairs of images, labels.