# How can I apply the same augmentation to a batch of images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, data-augmentation

I have a dataset of videos. Since the dataset is small, I am trying to augment the video data. I have not found any resources on augmenting videos, so what I think will work is -

1. Extract required frames from the video
2. Apply data augmentation to the extracted frames

Now, let's say I have extracted 20 frames from a single video. In order for my data to make sense, I will have to apply the same augmentation to these 20 frames. How can I achieve that? I am also open to other libraries if it makes the work easy.

I am guessing some changes to the `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(...)` arguments will do the trick. Here's the code snippet from Keras documentation.

```
ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    directory,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    classes=None,
    class_mode="categorical",
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    save_to_dir=None,
    save_prefix="",
    save_format="png",
    follow_links=False,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="nearest",
)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to set the `batch_size` equal to `number _of_frames`, or create your own [custom generator](https://towardsdatascience.com/writing-custom-keras-generators-fe815d992c5a)

Comment: I am not sure if applying the same augmentation to the images from the same video is the best approach in this case. While it does make more 'sense' as you said, I think that having different augmentations might force the network to really focus on the invariables in the data sequence and might end up helping with overfitting. But it does probably require a lot more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `tf.data.Dataset`, and apply transformations after the batching operation. This will require some work to make your own directory iterator (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149157/how-to-load-images-and-text-labels-for-cnn-regression-from-different-folders/65149339#65149339)), but here's the essence of it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data

cats = tf.concat([data.chelsea()[None, ...] for i in range(24)], axis=0)

test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(cats)


def augment(tensor):
    tensor = tf.cast(x=tensor, dtype=tf.float32)
    tensor = tf.divide(x=tensor, y=tf.constant(255.))
    tensor = tf.image.random_hue(image=tensor, max_delta=5e-1)
    tensor = tf.image.random_brightness(image=tensor, max_delta=2e-1)
    return tensor


test = test.batch(8).map(lambda x: augment(x))


fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.1, hspace=.2)
images = next(iter(test))
for index, image in enumerate(images):
    ax = plt.subplot(4, 2, index + 1)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.imshow(tf.clip_by_value(image, clip_value_min=0, clip_value_max=1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Not that for some reason, this doesn't work for `tf.image.random_flip_left_right`.